# Push server for iOS 4.0 onwards without using APNS

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Apple iOS 4.0 onwards, multitasking is supported.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945170/can-we-push-notification-without-using-apns) post, we can make use of this and write of push server of our own registering our app as providing VoIP services.

I would like to know how it is possible to do in details and would like to have server side implementation ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To register your app as a VoIP app, you must have this functionality, otherwise Apple  will reject it.

To use it, you can open a connexion between the server and the client using a socket, and for example show an alert when you have received some data.