# Is there possible make push notification without APNS

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I need to know if its possible to make push notifications without use the APNS.

And if it can be done, what are the best options?

Web server ->pushNotification-> Device

What about the VoIP apps? --> [Can we push notification without using APNs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945170/can-we-push-notification-without-using-apns)

Thanks.

Comment: I need to communicate Web server with device, also when the device stays in background mode. I've read something about VOiP apps, but, need some clarifications.

Comment: VoIP apps (such as Skype) are one of the three types of app permitted by Apple to run in the background. The other two are Location Services-based apps (such as Tom Tom Navigation) and Audio Streaming apps (such as Pandora and Spotify).

Comment: But can I make an VoIP/Location/Audio... app, that does is NOT an VoIP/Location/Audio... app, but that it works in background mode ? I get that 'idea' from here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945170/can-we-push-notification-without-using-apns

Comment: No you cannot declare you app to run in the background as a VoIp/Location/Audio without it actually doing one of those three things. Apple *will* reject any kind of app like that.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to use Push notification without APNS. This is restriction from Apple and is documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html)

Answer (score 1):

No you can not push notification to a device without using Apple's push notification service.

Comment: What about them?, you can register your app as a VOIP app, which will allow you to keep a socket open. Then they might use `UILocalNotification` to alert the user of a new call. Read this: [Tips for Developing a VoIP App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12)

Comment: Yes, but only if your app is a VOIP app. Misusing of the VOIP classification will get your app rejected.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to display push notifications for your application in the same way that the built in push notifications appear without using the Apple Push Notification Service.

You may be able to set up some kind of web socket-based solution, but that will not work when your app is in the background, thus defeating the point.

Answer (score -2):

Check out [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/)

> Push Composer makes sending Push Notifications simple for anyone in your organization. By putting the power of engagement into the hands of your business team, you can empower them to reach your customers quickly without adding strain on your engineering team. And because you can preview your message as you write it, you’ll know exactly how your users will see and engage with your message.